# How to use string inside an if statement with int?

Tags: c#

I am using a interger n
Example

```
 int n;
```

And a string with this syntax 1,2,3

Example

```
String numbers = "1,2,3";
```

I need to create an if statemant which it will compares int n with string numbers

My desired result want to be

```
if (n == 1 || n == 2 || n == 3)
```

How to combine this two variables?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? What is exactly the problem? Hints, string.Split, int.TryParse...

Comment: My problem is how to use string with int. Cause i will take error cant convert string to int

Comment: Do you mean to have `==` in your `if`?

Comment: Yea thats what i mean

Comment: So you need to find a way to convert the string into multiple ints. See the hints above

Comment: I can replace commas with || n = ... but will i use this in statement if n==

Comment: `var s = numbers.Split( ',' );`` 
`if( s.Any( n => { var i = int.Parse( n ); return i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3; } ) )`

Comment: By the way, in C# both 'int' and 'if' are all lowercase

Comment: What if i dont know how many number including my string?? Lets say i have 5 numbers 1,2,3,4,5. I need a code which its global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try *Linq*, `Any` e.g.

```
string numbers = "1,2,3";

// if "n" equals to Any of the item in the numbers:
if (numbers.Split(',').Any(item => int.Parse(item) == n)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways. I'll cover two.

First, you need to separate your string into individual numbers.

```
  //notice, no caps on Int, otherwise you'd need Int32 as the declaration
        int n = GetSomeValueSoNEqualsSomething(); 
    //String and string are both correct, but try to use the lowercase for variables,
    // uppercase for class methods.
        string numbers = "1,2,3"; 
    //split the string into an array of strings delimiting by comma
        string[] nums = numbers.Split(',');
    //now, you can either check against the string 
        return nums.Contains(n.ToString()); //string compare to return a bool
    //or check via a loop and parse the numbers
        foreach (var s in nums)
        { if(int.Parse(s) == n) return true; } //int compare to return a bool
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your string array might contain things that don't parse out as integers:

```
String numbers = "1,2,3";

var intNumbers = new List<int>();

foreach (var item in numbers.Split(','))
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(item, out i))
        intNumbers.Add(i);
}

if (intNumbers.Any(i => i >=1 || i <= 3))
{
    // Found!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can trust your input (be careful), you can do it in one line:

```
if (numbers.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Contains(n))
{
    Do stuff;
}
```

This splits the string into an array of strings, then selects each item and parses it, combining those results into an `IEnumerable<int>`, which you can then check to see if it contains n.

Comment: I trust my input so i will try your example and i will come back soon

Comment: I would recommend you try both other answers first.  This statement is hiding fundamental logic you need to know and understand.  You will also want to learn the syntax of this statement, but the others explain better what this compressed statement is doing step-by-step